# How can you manipulate a string to equal the length of another string?

Tags: python, string

For example, I have the string `s1 = "lets go to the mall"`
and a second string `s2 = "hello"`

In Python, how can I manipulate the `s2` string to equal the length of `s1`.

`s2` would then look like:

`s2 = "hellohellohellohell"` which would have the same number of characters as `s1`.

Comment: Look into string multiplication and slicing.

Comment: python strings are immutable, so you won't be able to change `s2` in-place. however, you can create a new string with length equal to `s1`

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach:

```
s1 = 'lets go to the mall'
s2 = 'hello'
s2 = ''.join(s2[i % len(s2)] for i in range(len(s1)))
print(s2)  # "hellohellohellohell"
```

**Edit**: Here's an explanation for those not as familiar with Python or programming =]

- `''.join(...)` takes an *iterable*, which is something you can iterate through, and joins all of those elements together with the empty string in between. So, if what's on the inside is an *iterable* of letters, it'll join all of those letters together.
- `range(len(s1))` produces an iterable of all numbers `0` to `len(s1) - 1`. The number of numbers in this iterable is equal to the length of `s1`.
- `s2[i]` means the letter in the string `s2` at index `i`. So, if `s2 = 'hello'`, then `s2[0] = 'h'`, `s2[1] = 'e'`, etc.
- `i % len(s2)` means `i` modulo `len(s2)`, or the remainder when you divide `i` by the length of `s2`.
- So, putting that all together, this code first creates an iterable of letters looping through `s2` as many times as it needs to in order to get `len(s1)` many letters, then joins them all together with the empty string in between.

Comment: Cleanest solution by far.

Comment: Instead of building the string up one letter at a time, build it up one copy of `s2` at a time, then trim the excess off the end. `''.join(s2 for i in range(0,len(s1),len(s2)))[:len(s1)]` (which is similar to some of the other answers).

Comment: @chepner I think all of the solutions here have pros and cons. For this solution, I wanted to go for readability/cleanliness over optimizing for string concatenation and performance. I do think other solutions are likely faster, but I found this easier to comprehend than the slicing approaches :)

Comment: Agreed; my own answer is *extremely* inefficient, but very short :)

Comment: I smiled when I saw that! I think your solution is probably the best in terms of speed, but maybe not so much on memory ;) I think mine isn't as speedy, but seems pretty memory-efficient in that it doesn't create additional string to chop off later. But of course, all of this is pretty trivial in most practical situations.

Answer (score 2):

[Itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html) is the answer. More specifically [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```
import itertools

s1 = "lets go to the mall"
s2 = "Hello"

print ("".join(s for _, s in itertools.takewhile(lambda t: t[0] < len(s1), enumerate(itertools.cycle(s2)))))
```

Or even simpler (using [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)):

```
print ("".join(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(s2)), len(s1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`//` is integer division which finds the whole multiples.
`%` is the modulo (remainder)

Multiply `s2` my the number of times it can go into `s1` and then use slicing to add the remaining portion of `s2`.

```
s3 = s2 * (len(s1) // len(s2)) + s2[:(len(s1) % len(s2))]

>>> s3
'hellohellohellohell'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(s2 * (len(s1)//len(s2) + 1))[:len(s1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically multiply `s2` by the `math.floor` of the two lengths divided, then add the remainder of the string:

```
def extend(s1, s2):
    return s2*int(math.floor(len(s1)/len(s2)))+s2[:len(s1) % len(s2)]
```

---

```
>>> extend("lets go to the mall", "hello")
'hellohellohellohell'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Off of the top of my head, and you'll have to forgive me, you could use a function like this:

```
def string_until_whenever(s1, s2):
i = len(s1)
x = 0
newstring = ""
while i != 0:
    newstring = newstring + s2[x]
    x += 1
    i -= 1
    if x == len(s2) - 1:
         x = 0
return newstring
```

Answer (score 0):

Inefficient, but simple. (The multiplication makes a string much longer than it needs to be.)

```
n = len(s1)
s3 = (s2*n)[:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many possible solutions. amongst many possible solutions my answer is :

```
s2 = s2*(len(s1)/len(s2)+1)
s2 = s2[0:len(s1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be the cleanest solution but you can also do this, using string multiplication and string slicing:

```
def string_until_whenever(s1, s2):
    temp = ""    
    if len(s2) > len(s1):
        temp = s2
        s2 = s1
        s1 = temp

    new_string = ""
    multiply_by = len(s1)/len(s2)
    modulo = len(s1) % len(s2)    
    new_string = s2 * multiply_by
    new_string = new_string + s2[0:modulo]    

    return new_string


print(string_until_whenever("lets go to the mall", "hello"))
#Outputs: hellohellohellohell
```